# When would the data set be stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I am not a statistician or mathematician and I need some help. I did three experiments as I labeled on the figure, 3,4,5, each experiment has x and y results. The markers are the real data and the lines are fitted lines I draw. Clearly, there is a trend to go up, but I want to know when the data is relatively stationary? or in another word, when the change of the data is relative small. Is there any relevant test I can use? I tried to differentiate the trend line and try to find when the change is small, but the result is not clear and and hard to tell.

Thanks for your help!!!!
[image]

Comment: There are statistical tests (eg. Dicky-Fuller) for the existence of a unit root (i.e. random walk) in time series data, but often the best approach is to think carefully about specifics of your experimental setting. Can the y-axis variable wander off in either direction in an unbounded fashion? Can it keep going up for forever?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic linear regression hypothesis test. To find out if the slope is not 0, you need to reject the null hypothesis that the slope is 0. [Paraphrasing this website](http://stattrek.com/regression/slope-test.aspx?Tutorial=AP):

1. Calculate the standard error (SE).
2. Calculate the degrees of freedom (n-2) where n is the number of points in one of your experiments.
3. Calculate the t statistic = b/SE where b is the slope.
4. Use the t-distribution calculator in the link above to calculate the p value. If the p value is less than 0.05, then you really do have a trend.

Comment: These curves exhibit visual evidence of substantial positive serial correlation, which would imply the standard error you recommend is likely too small and therefore the p-value will be too small--perhaps much too small.  Several of them also exhibit important forms of lack of fit, especially at the earliest times, which calls into question the applicability of this approach.

Comment: @whuber the standard error is calculated relative to the predicted value so the correlation that you mention is taken into account. Yes, you would need to look to see if the residuals are normally distributed - but by eye - there looks to be as much residual at early times as there are at later times.

Comment: (1) Your description about "standard error ... predicted value" does not address the serial correlation issue at all.  (2) The lack of fit is not a deviation from normality of residuals: it is a failure of the assumed line to come anywhere close to the data for certain times.

Comment: (1) it does: if there is a series correlation then the SE is low. You would have to pick the point in time that you want to test for correlation and then see if it actually disproves the null hypothesis.